# Parse.com - Set ACL in .csv for importing

Tags: android, ios, csv, parse-platform, acl

I'm trying to import a database into a class. When I import my csv file, all the rows have Public Read/Write access for the ACL. I have a few questions regarding how to set the ACL to public read only.

1. How do I change the ACL to only public read in my .csv file so that when I import the file all the ACLs are set to public read only?
2. Is there a way to set the default ACL of the class to public read so that anything I import into that class will automatically set the ACL to public read only?

My current alternative solution is to have some background CloudCode job scanning through all the rows (group of 1000) and setting the ACL for them 1 by 1 after I've imported all the data. However, I'm expecting 10's of thousands of rows and I'm worried that this will either be very slow in the future or use up a lot of requests per second when I run the job dozens of times sequentially.

Thank you.

-Kelvin

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you've figured this out, but if anyone else searches this question in the future -

In the dashboard for you're class, just click the "Security" button:

[image]

Then in the popup you can set class-level permissions:

[image]